Request not reaching the container server while tailing logs in redhat 9.3 OS containing podman and request to authenticate the Freeradius executed
Request not reaching the container server while tailing logs in redhat 9.3 OS containing podman and request to authenticate the Freeradius user is executed
I have 2 machines:
1: Machine on which main application is installed
2. Machine on which FreeRADIUS server is configured and cointainer is created
The Freeradius server machine is redhat 9.3 machine in which podman is installed , now when i execute the request from the NTRadpin i am not gettign any logs in the freeradius container in freeradius server machine , i used below command to create the cintainer:
docker run -d -p 1812:1812/udp -e TV_URL=http://[IP Address]/TokenValidator/TokenValidator.asmx -e  CLIENT_API_URL=http://[IP Address]/radius/api/radius/clients -e VERIFY_TV_CERTIFICATE=no -e FAILOVER_RESTART=yes -v [Path in FreeRAFIUS server machine to mount]:[Path inside the FreeRADIUS container] --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 -e LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG -e UPDATER_SCHEDULE_MINS=0 --name FreeRADIUSv3 [ Image Name]
Note: I added the required auth Node manually in the container
I wanted to authenticated the user in my application using the NTRadpin application which sends request to FreeRADIUS server machine and authenticates the user in the form of response Accepted\
but while sending request from NTRadpin to freeradius server , no logs are displaying in the logs in the Freeradius server
I blocked the firewall inside the Freeradius server machine (having theredhat 9.3 version with podman installed) as well
